# Custom listview is not fully displayed ( cropped from bottom)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

[image: Bottom news is cropped]

I'm new to Android development. To learn new concepts I started developing a news app.
Made a custom listView. But in the bottom, news is cropped. Some part of the news is covered..

How can I correct this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="112dp" >
```

Above is the XML file of the main activity. Still Couldn't find the Issue with the last news is not fully displayed. It is cropped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Business">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_business"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:progress="0" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/business_news_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Above is the XML code of where the ListView is inserted.

Comment: add margin to the listview to take a better look `android:layout_margin="2dp"`

Comment: added 2dp, 5dp, 10 dp layout margin. It didn't work. though progressively more and more of the last news was visible. Added 50dp. now the bottom news is fully visible. Will it be a problem in a mobile having different size screen.??? (because there is a margin of 50dp from bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your listview is not cropped. It just takes all the available space as you have set in xml:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

So the last one is not fully visible. This is what you see.  
if you set `android:layout_margin="2dp"` for your listview you will see its boundaries.